# Add one column after groupby function

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a column according to the following condition.

```
  df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : ['M1', 'M1', 'M1', 'M2', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4', 'M4'], 'Total': [1,2,3,21,15,42,1,2,25,4]})
```

Expected Output:

```
X Total P

M1 1 P1

M1 2 P2

M1 3 P3

M2 21 P1

M2 15 P2

M3 42 P1

M4 1 P1

M4 2 P2

M4 25 P3

M4 4 P4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `X` column, aggregate with the `cumcount` and add `P` as a prefix:

```
df['P'] = 'P'+df.groupby('X').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

   X   Total   P
0  M1      1  P1
1  M1      2  P2
2  M1      3  P3
3  M2     21  P1
4  M2     15  P2
5  M3     42  P1
6  M4      1  P1
7  M4      2  P2
8  M4     25  P3
9  M4      4  P4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['P'] = df.groupby(['X'])['Total'].agg({"p":"cumcount"})+1
df['P'] = 'P'+df['p'].astype(str)
print(df)
```

```
    X   Total  P
0  M1      1  P1
1  M1      2  P2
2  M1      3  P3
3  M2     21  P1
4  M2     15  P2
5  M3     42  P1
6  M4      1  P1
7  M4      2  P2
8  M4     25  P3
9  M4      4  P4
```